# Replace a specific part of a string using MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string

I have many Strings in the database Like

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-qTiYA1WiY8&index=8&list=PLPNcLSfYNC3Dw535smncyHRCBRmdf1Bti"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I want to change these in a way like,

**Original:** `www.youtube.com/embed/-qTiYA1WiY8&index=8&list=PLPNcLSfYNC3Dw535smncyHRCBRmdf1Bti`
**Desired:-** `www.youtube.com/embed/-qTiYA1WiY8`

So the final String can be converted to

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-qTiYA1WiY8"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I can do this using php but I prefer to do it with a mysql query

I tried to use:

```
UPDATE MyTable

    SET StringColumn = REPLACE (StringColumn, 'SearchForThis', 'ReplaceWithThis')
```

It needs to be a general solution that can replace string from **&** and before **"** if exist in a String

Comment: This could be done in mysql level but will become pretty ugly query with substring_index and replace functions, the best would be to handle this on application level using PHP.

Comment: this could be done in 1 line using Mysql otherwise will have to setup cron jobs as the database is huge

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do what you want

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET StringColumn = REPLACE (StringColumn, CONCAT('&', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(StringColumn, '"', 2), '&', -2)), '')
WHERE ConditionColumn = <CONDITION>
```

assuming that the value of src contains two instances of `&` and is enclosed in double quotes

Answer (score -2):

use as per below-

```
UPDATE mytable SET stringcolumn=SUBSTRING_INDEX(stringcolumn,'&',1);
```

You can check your output before updation by below query-

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(stringcolumn,'&',1) FROM mytable;
```

Comment: I will be thankful if also share reason of -ve voting.